# jquery - addClass on selected link

Tags: jquery, css

This should be simple, but I just can't get it to work

My list

```
<div id="ctMenu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">WELCOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

My CSS

```
#ctMenu { width:1010px; margin: 20px 0 0 0; padding:20px 0 20px 0}
#ctMenu ul { margin:0; padding:0;}
#ctMenu ul li { margin-left: 0; margin-bottom:0;  display:inline;}
#ctMenu ul li a { padding: 10px 25px 9px 25px; background-color:green; text-decoration: none; color:Black; font-weight:bold; }
#ctMenu ul li a:hover {background-color:Gray; }
.selected { background-color: yellow; }
```

My jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ctMenu ul li a').click(function () {
            $('#ctMenu ul li a').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        });
    });
```

I'm just trying to set the css to the class ".selected" when someone clicks a link. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barryman9000/qcHJQ/2/)

Comment: in your jsfiddle you didnt select to include the jquery library, that's why the 'selected' class is not added to your link.  
and as defined in the answers below, your css is the culprit for the style not being displayed.

Comment: @Sander - Thanks! I saw that, changed it and it still wasn't working. I think I left off the closing div in the jsfiddle.

Comment: @MarkB: For your reference, refer to the fix which I have given too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that you declared a stronger CSS rule `#ctMenu ul li a` that overrides the `.selected`. Try this CSS rule instead:

```
#ctMenu ul li a.selected { background-color: yellow; }
```

Comment: It's still not adding the 'selected' class to my link

Comment: Yes... it does. I must just not know how to use jsFiddle or something. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Marian & @Mark: small update.. this change is not required.. Mark mentioned CSS is fine and if he replace the line to `$('#ctMenu ul li a').removeClass('selected').removeAttr("class");` this then it works..  This I have tested on **Firefox** using **firebug** plugin.

Comment: Siva, i suggest you try to comprehend what mark is trying to do first. He didn't say the CSS was fine, he just said it doesn't work. Your proposed solution doesn't solve the problem and further more there's no need to get rid of the class attribute.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder: Thanks for posting. When I test it using **Firebug**, I can see **class** attribute still exists. If though **UI** works fine but backend shows wrong. That is the reason why I have provided a solution where **class** attribute is removed, on the click of another link. I feel thats the way should work. If am wrong, please correct. Am not pointing any one that they are wrong, just am giving my solution, which may help to fullfill the code from  all angels.

Answer (score 1):

here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FnWzR/).

to understand this, you should read about [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity).

Note that `#ctMenu ul li a.selected { background-color: yellow }` is more specific than .selected and that's why it works.

Comment: Thanks for the specificity link

Answer (score 0):

This time am fully tested on **Firebug** its working fine..

Replace this

```
$('#ctMenu ul li a').removeClass('selected');
```

To

```
$('#ctMenu ul li a').removeClass('selected').removeAttr("class");
```

Reason behind doing this change is:- at this point **class** attribute is still exists and `class="selected"` is changing, when a user is clicked. But if you add `.removeAttr("class")` then on click of another link existing **class** attribute will be removed. Your code will be a full pleged one..

you can test this with **FireBug** on **Firefox**

Comment: Where do you add the 'selected' class to the <a />?

Comment: Your code remains same. You need to replace the mentioned line to the one which I mentioned. Try this and let me know your feedback

Comment: keep in mind that this code is good in this situation but needs to be used with care... if a designer makes a theme for your site, and adds a new class to certain items (who knows for what reason) your removeAttr("class") will remove the other classes as well... i think you need to use this with care at least..